# LtSpice simulate the temperature rise of MOSFETS

Tags: ltspice

I would like to simulate the temperature rise of M1 given a certain temperature, but i dont know how to. All the components in the schematics have spice model ready.

[image]

If the load was constant i could have done this manually using the junction to ambient temperature, but the mosfet M1 has a PWM input which makes thing a bit more difficult, thus i turn to simulation.

Comment: Do you know how to plot the power dissipation for a given part? (V(source_node) - V(drain_node)) * I(R1) for example. Then CTRL+ left click on the formula in the plot and it'll average it for you.

Comment: @Unimportant I did not know about the CTRL + left click, but its only the average though, i would like to seen the temperature rise so i can know how long it took to reach a certain temepratures

Comment: You can use that average to calculate the temperature rise manually as you said.

Comment: @Unimportant but that doesnt tell me the time it took to reach a certain temperature

Comment: Time to reach temperature is beyond a simple simulation tool. You need to know the specific heat capacity of stuff to do that. But, the MOSFET data sheet will give you most of the information except how you are taking heat away from the device.

Answer (score 1):

Hold ALT key and then  <strike>right</strike>  left click on the component, you get power dissipation for the selected component.

Then hold CTRL and click on the trace. You'll get a window of calculated power, energy,... You have to calculate the temperature rise according to heat transfer formula - it depends on the heatsink you are using, PCB size, environment temperature, ...

[image]

For this example a power dissipation is 240mW, let's say that \$R_{thJA}\$ (Thermal resistance Junction to Air) is approximately 150K/W on a small PCB footprint would yield 36K of temperature rise above the air temperature.

Comment: Did you mean `ALT + LClick`?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes. ALT + LClick

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look in *Documents/LTspiceXVII/lib/sub/SOAtherm-NMOS.lib*. The library file describes the way the powers are calculated, together with the thermal constants as RC ladder filters. You'll see that the powers are calculated, more or less, as the products of currents and voltages through and across the device, while the RC filters are calculated such that their response matches or come close to what the datasheets have to say.